# How can I combine these two arrays into a matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, concatenation

In MATLAB, if I define 2 matrices like:

```
A = [1:10];
B = [1:11];
```

How do I make matrix `C` with column 1 equal to `A` and column 2 equal to `B`? I cannot find any answers online. Sorry if I used the wrong MATLAB terminology for this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to accomplish this you first need to make sure that `A` and `B` are the same length. In your example, `A` has 10 elements and `B` has 11, so that won't work.

However, assuming `A` and `B` have the same number of elements, this will do the trick:

```
C = [A(:) B(:)];
```

This first reshapes `A` and `B` into column vectors using [single-colon indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egbu-1), then [concatenates them horizontally](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html).

Comment: If A and B are row vectors, the transpose operator ' (assuming A and B are real matrices) will do the job. A(:) vectorize A (usually denotes Vec(A))

Comment: if A and B are not the same length, you can pad them with zeros (or some other number or NaN) so that they are:   A((end:1):length(B)) = 0; B((end+1):length(A)) = 0;

Answer (score 1):

if A,B same length, then can just type

```
C=[A' B']
```